# Do the irreducible representations of a finite group separate its points?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Given a finite group $G$ and a field $k$, is it always true that the irreducible representations over $k$ of $G$ separate the points of $G$? More precisely, given $x,y\in G$ such that $x\neq y$ can we always find an irreducible representation $\rho$ of $G$ such that $\rho(x)\neq\rho(y)$? Do we need to impose some conditions on $k$, e.g. that it is algebraically closed, for this to be true?

I know that the result is true when $k=\mathbb{C}$, since it follows from the much more general [Gelfand Raikov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Raikov_theorem), but this seems a bit of an overkill to me and I was wondering if there was a simpler argument. Also, this argument doesn’t apply to a more general $k$.

Comment: No, this is false in general. For example, it is false if $G$ is a $p$-group and $k$ has characteristic $p$. I suspect it is also false in general, in the semi-simple case, if $k$ is not algebraically closed. If $G$ is dihedral things work out nicely over $\mathbb R$, though.